# Is Obfuscar able to skip obfuscating namespace but still obfuscate all its subtypes?

Tags: c#, obfuscar

According to the documentation, it is possible to skip the entire namespace:

```
<Module file="$(InPath)\AssemblyX.exe">
    <!-- skip a namespace -->
    <SkipNamespace name="Company.PublicBits" />
```

All the subtypes (classes) under Company.PublicBits will also be skipped.
But I am looking for a way to only not obfuscate namespace itself, but still obfuscate all its subtypes. Is it possible to be done by configuration?

Comment: Have you read the `Obfuscar` documentation? This would be the first action I would do *before* asking a question. Does their docs state that it is possible? If not then there are two options: their docs are awful or you just can't do it. I'd say more likely it would then be option 2. If not, you should consider not using it anymore because if there are no good docs the software is likely to be as good as the docs are.

Comment: I did -- http://docs.obfuscar.com/en/latest/getting-started/configuration.htm
And on documentation there is no information about it. Looks like an extra script to manually find all namespace and create rules for each individually.

Comment: okay :) then you'll get my upvote in order to find a solution for that  anyway -- as stated "no good docs, (probably) no good to use software"

Comment: Currently there is no feature like you asked for. Pull requests are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by 'only not obfuscate namespace itself'? Can you explain it little bit more?

Comment: Feature still missing? That could be helpful if already exists. I'm facing a problem while creating a CorelDraw Addon... I want to obfuscate the methods but keep the namespace the same, if namespace changes, Addon is not loaded.

Comment: Update: Solved my problem simplely changing ```class MyClass``` to ```public class MyClass``` this way the obfuscator isn't messing up my code and preserving the namespace.